# VBA to use Format Painter to copy format from Column to Column

Tags: excel, format, vba

For part of a VBA I am writing I need to copy the format for all of Column I into all of Column J.  I figure I should use the format painter.  I know this should be easy but I have never done any VBA for format painting, can anyone advise?  Again, need to copy format from Column I to the next column (J).  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Recorded a macro and adjusted it for the UsedRange only:

```
Public Sub copyColFormat()

    With Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange

        .Columns("I").Copy
        .Columns("J").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

        .Cells(1).Select
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Option Explicit with no variable declared. Flagged =P

Comment: "Bad" habbits ;) actually, I'll remove it for the sake of simplicity... (@findwindow)